# Проблема с кодировкой utf-16LE с BOM в Python 2.7

Tags: unicode, кодировка, python-2.7

Имеется файл словаря. Кодировка неизвестна. Вот фрагмент, файл открыт в vim:

[image: Фрагмент],

Как видно, транскрипция читается правильно.
Задача: распарсить файл и перегрузить его в другой файл, также правильно читаемый, т.е. с сохранением транскрипции.
Далее, загружаю этот файл в Python и построчно читаю:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...    
hf = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in hf:
    ...
    ...
```

Что-то загружается, смотрю в дебагере:

[image: PyCharm]

После загрузки "этого" в другой файл транскрипция теряется, причём часть символов остаётся читабельной, но не такой, как надо, а часть представлена непечатными символами типа <8a>, <97>, ^B и .т.д. Примечательно то, что vim транскрипцию в новом файле уже не распознаёт правильно, показывает либо не то, что надо, либо перевёрнутый знак вопроса.

Шаманство с кодированием-перекодированием ничего не дала. Использование штучек типа ftfy, chardet - тоже без результата. В частности, ftfy исправляет непечатные символы на печатные, но неверно.

Вот так исходный файл выглядит в HEX:

[image: HEXEDIT]

Выделен как раз символ транскрипции.
Что можно с этим сделать?

Добавлено:::

В общем, определил, что исходная кодировка - utf-16LE с BOM. Определил не я, а редактор Geany))
Но что теперь с этим делать в Python - не знаю. Вот это:

```
hf = os.open(file,encoding="utf-16LE")
```

не помогает: при каждой итерации в строке, где есть неудобный символ транскрипции вылетает exception кодировки.

Решил проблему пересохранением файла с помощью Geany. Костыль, но не знаю, как питонячьим способом решить задачу.

Comment: Попробуйте `hf = open(sys.argv[1], encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: TypeError: encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: А если так `import io` + `hf = io.open(sys.argv[1], encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte